# Grouping columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would be grateful if someone could help me with a pandas dataframe problem I am having.

I am trying to group a pandas dataframe by columns but am unsure how to proceed.  I have a dataframe with duplicate column names (A's and B's) and would like to group these to return the maximum value of A's and B's

**Duplicate Column Dataframe**

```
index      | A | A | A | B | B |
--------------------------------
2015-01-01 |   | 1 | 7 | 1 |   |
--------------------------------
2015-01-02 | 3 |   |   |   | 5 |
```

**Dataframe after processing**

```
index      | A | B |
--------------------
2015-01-01 | 7 | 1 |
---------------------
2015-01-02 | 3 | 5 |

unique_cols = [A,B]   
df.groupby(by = cols, axis = 1).max()
```

This does not work as I get an error message about the Grouper not 1-dimensional.  I have also tried transposing the dataframe and grouping by the rows.  However I get an IndexError message (*index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0*)

**Question:**

How do you group a dataframe with duplicate columns to return the maximum from them from the group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need first filter columns by subset and then `groupby` by all columns values by `level=0` with `axis=1`:

```
cols = ['A','B']   
df = df[cols].groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).max()
print (df)
              A    B
index               
2015-01-01  7.0  1.0
2015-01-02  3.0  5.0
```

Last if necessary cast to `int`:

```
df = df[cols].groupby(level = 0, axis = 1).max().astype(int)
print (df)
            A  B
index           
2015-01-01  7  1
2015-01-02  3  5
```

Comment: Thank you, I spent a long time trying to figure that out and you made it look very easy!